# Resume trouble: how does kernel know it is supposed to resume?

Tags: suspend

Today I have a new suspend/resume problem. On Dell Precision 5510 w/Ubuntu 17.04, all was well. But now, resume is not working. I always get restart.

Yesterday, I had a runaway script and it paralyzed the UI. I made a programming error, it caused this script to consume all system resources.  I went to another  computer and ssh connected with this "frozen" computer. I tried to shut down the system the old fashioned way:

```
/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

However, after 20 minutes of  waiting, I gave up and held down the power button. The thing will start, it will suspend also. If I open the lid, it wakes up automatically. That is how I know the machine is actually suspended, it starts itself.

However, the machine restarts, instead of resuming, after a suspend.

My working theory is that the unclean crash damaged a settings file that must be rewritten during suspend. This file is a signal that resume from RAM is OK, rather than a restart.

I don't know for sure there is such a file for suspend/resume, but I've found comments here about hybernate/resume which say that it uses a state file to tell if it can try to restore a session.

I expect this problem will disappear at random after some package updates, but it has made me really curious about how a system checks to see if it should restart.

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared after shutting down, restarting, and then shutting down again, and then restarting.  After that, I've survived 3 suspend/resumes without the unexpected restart.

Still, I'm curious to understand how this works, how the kernel knows to resume rather than suspend.